# Why is id = 5 defined as null here?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have to color a certain path in svg by condition.
I can't understand why, when I iterate through an array with objects, all **id = 1...9** return null, and the rest return an integer value.

Because of this, an error occurs:

> ***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setAttribute')at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous>***

Which informs me that it cannot find an element with an empty id. How do I solve this issue, I'm a beginner)

[There is a part of my code here](https://playcode.io/1583080):

```
const date = [
  { id: '22', name: 'Алтайский край', value: 29 },
  { id: '42', name: 'Кемеровская область - Кузбасс', value: 43 },
  { id: '65', name: 'Сахалинская область', value: 32 },
  { id: '75', name: 'Забайкальский край', value: 28 },
  { id: '05', name: 'Республика Дагестан', value: 45 }
];

for (let i of date) {
  let id = Number(i.id);
  // console.log(typeof id);
  if (i.value > 24 && i.value < 50) {
        if (document.getElementById(id) == null) console.log(id)
        document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('fill', '#f7a35c');
  }
}
```

I tried using ***DOMContentLoaded***, but it didn't help.

Comment: Which of these lines throws that error? What have you tried to resolve it? Where are you stuck?

Comment: `Number("05") === 5` and that doesn't match `id="05"`

Comment: You're missing an `else`. The `setAttribute` gets called even if the element is not found.

Comment: @NicoHaase follow the link and you will understand
I tried to edit the data format itself somehow, I used DOMContentLoaded, it didn't help, everything works fine with the array, except for the data where id = "01" ... "09", in this example it is id = "05".

Comment: @AKX can you show me visually

Comment: [Showing visually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMgRr.png)

Comment: "follow the link" - no, thanks. Please add all relevant details to your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all why are you converting string to Number.
If your id = "05" then Number("05") === 5

That that why it wont find any element with id=5 thus returning null.

Comment: That is a comment already made

Comment: I realized everything, thank you)

Answer (score -1):

To simplify:

- you don't need to cast the ID to a number (and implicitly back again)
- you're missing an `else` so the `setAttribute` gets called even if the element is not found.

```js
const datas = [
  { id: '1', name: 'a', value: 29 },
  { id: '3', name: 'b', value: 43 },
  { id: '8', name: 'c', value: 32 },
];

for (let datum of datas) {
  if (datum.value > 24 && datum.value < 50) {
    const el = document.getElementById(datum.id);
    if(el) el.setAttribute('fill', '#f7a35c');
    else console.warn("Not found: element with ID", datum.id);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" fill="#bcc5d9">
  <rect id="1" x="10" y="10" width="50" height="50" />
  <rect id="2" x="70" y="10" width="50" height="50" />
  <rect id="3" x="10" y="70" width="50" height="50" />
  <rect id="4" x="70" y="70" width="50" height="50" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I realized everything. Since this is part of the code and part of the function, else I specified later